# Nested functions error, Unexpected token ':', Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, namespaces, nested-function, javascript-namespaces

I want to make my code more clear, that the reason i am trying to learn namespaces or nested functions. I've read about them in several places and as i understood `'Revealing Module'` is the best option. So i tried to copy second example from this post [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41962097/11900594).

At first, i got the error when trying to return object with two methods: `Unexpected token ':'`. When i tried to return one method instead of 2, i got the `Cannot read property of undefined` error when tried to call `applyEvents` of `expandableElements` object.

```
let expandableElements = 
(
    function() 
    {
        // All expandable elements
        let expands = document.querySelectorAll(".expand-icon");

        // Apply events to all .expand-icon elements
        function applyExpandEvents()
        {
            for(let i = 0; i < expands.length; i++)
            {
                expands[i].addEventListener("click", expandList);
            }

            // Expand method
            function expandList() 
            {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                let content = this.previousElementSibling;

                if (content.style.maxHeight)
                {
                    content.style.padding = "0";

                    content.style.maxHeight = null;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    content.style.padding = "1rem";
                    content.style.paddingBottom = "0.5rem";

                    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 20 + "px";
                } 
            }
        }


        // Close all expanded lists
        function closeAllExpands()
        {
            for(let i = 0; i < expands.length; i++)
            {
                let expand = expands[i];

                if(expand.classList.contains("active"))
                {
                    expand.classList.toggle("active");

                    expand.previousSibling.style.padding = "0";
                    expand.previousSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return 
        {
            applyEvents : applyExpandEvents,
            closeAll    : closeAllExpands // Unexpected token ':'
        };
    }
)();

expandableElements.applyEvents(); // If remove closeAll from return, then'Cannot read property applyEvents of undefined'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` and the JSON must be on the same line. As soon as the return line is executed, the control is handed over to the caller (with `undefined`) and the JSON line never get executed.

do it like this:

```
...
        return {
            applyEvents : applyExpandEvents,
            closeAll    : closeAllExpands // Unexpected token ':'
        };
```

**Detailed Explanation** from [MDN docs about return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return):

> The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and the expression.

```
return
a + b;
```

is transformed by ASI into:

```
return; 
a + b;
```

Comment: what the hell lol?)) i don't like when first brace on the same line, why this even an issue?))

Comment: I've explained the reason. please  take a look at it